# find all words that contains `p` but not `ph`

Tags: javascript, regex

Say,

```
str = 'python php ruby javascript jsonp perhapsphpisoutdated'
```

How do you find all words that contains `p` but not `ph` using regex?

I know how to solve it with `split`&`filter`:

```
str.split(' ')
  .filter( w=>w.includes('p') && !w.includes('ph') )
```

Is there a possible regex way?

Comment: And what is the correct answer here?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Isn't the question clear enough?

Comment: I mean, if the word contains `p` with no `h` after it, and `ph`, this must be ignored? I get 3 now.

Comment: Use this as a simple test. Would you match on the word "prophecy"? That has a p and it also has a ph. If wiktor is right, then you would exclude the word because it contains a ph. Looking again at your question, I'm inclined to agree with that. My solution (if you wanted to look for that pattern in a word) would match on prophecy because there is a p without a ph and the ph later in the word is irrelevant.

Comment: Try [this](http://regexr.com/3e8mg), this will skip all words that contains "ph"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use the following solution:

```js
var str = 'python php ruby javascript jsonp perhapsphpisoutdated';
var res = str.match(/\b(?!\w*ph)\w*p\w*/g);
console.log(res);
```

**Description**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?!\w*ph)` - a *negative lookahead* requiring that there cannot be `ph` after 0+ word chars that appear right after the leading word boundary
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars
- `p` - a letter `p`
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars.

**Note** that `\w` matching letters, digits and underscores can be replaced with `[a-zA-Z]` to only match ASCII letters.

**Visualization**:

[image: https://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=%5Cb(%3F!%5Cw*ph)%5Cw*p%5Cw*]

Comment: FYI, here is [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tY2pI6/2). To match case-insensitively, use `/\b(?!\w*ph)\w*p\w*/gi`

Comment: Well, I read the question as "get the *count* of the words" - the `.length` is redundant if words themselves should be extracted. Thank you, @jcubic.

Comment: Neat image. What system/website gave you that output. I could use that for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually something you could do a number of different ways. I suggest you use https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/ and look at the quantifiers and matching. You might also read up on look ahead http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Here are a couple of ideas.

`p{1}h{0}`  this says exactly 1 p followed by exactly 0 h

`p[^h]` this says p followed by anything which is not h (this won't match "p" by itself)

`p(?!h)` I LIKE THIS ONE BEST as it uses the look-ahead feature of Regex. It says p, is it followed by an 'h'? No? That's good then.

Good luck.

Comment: That is what I though to use, too, but it seems `perhapsphpisoutdated` should also be excluded from the count as it contains `ph`.

Comment: I may be reading your requirement incorrectly. I would have thought that was allowed because it was matching on p. I was looking to exclude any uses of ph, but if you are looking to exclude any WORD which contains ph, then Wiktor's solution is better.

Comment: `/p{1}h{0}/` has exactly the same semantics as `/p/`.  `{0}` is only useful in flavors that support subroutine calls (JavaScript doesn't), and `{1}` is pure noise.

Comment: Agreed, but my point is that you could get the effect with multiple regex. You'll notice that I only did that once to be pedantic.

Comment: My point is that `h{0}` doesn't prevent matching if there's an `h`, like `(?!h)` would.  It doesn't do *anything*.  If you quantify something with `{0}`, you effectively remove it from the regex.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://regexr.com/3e8ms) won't match any word that contains "ph" or does not contain "p".

```
\b(?:p(?!h)|[^p\s])*?p(?!h)(?:p(?!h)|[^p\s])*?\b
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you executable code, I interchange the sequence of !w.includes('ph') & w.includes('p'). And javascript execution of statment

```js
var str = 'python php ruby javascript jsonp perhapsphpisoutdated';
var res=str.split(' ').filter( w=> !w.includes('ph') && w.includes('p') )
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP is already doing.  The question was how to do the same thing with a regex.